# Setting focus on a button is not working

Tags: jquery, setfocus

I am trying to set the focus to a button while the user presses the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key in the text box. But it is not working. I am using the Internet Explorer 8 browser. Am I missing something?

```
$("input.Box").live('keydown', function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        e.preventDefault(); 
        $("#button").focus(); // Not working?
    }
});
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Microsoft decided that they don't like `e.keyCode` and instead have their own syntax, `e.which`.

You have to check for both:

```
$("input.Box").live('keydown', function(e) {
    var keyCode = (window.event) ? e.which : e.keyCode;

    if (keyCode == 13)
        e.preventDefault(); 
        $("#button").focus(); // Not working?
    }
});
```

Answer (score 12):

The problem is that IE is not able to respond quickly enough, so you need to add a small  delay between when the `live` function is entered, and when `.focus()` is called. So, replace

`$("#button").focus();`

with

```
setTimeout(function () {
 $('#button').focus();
}, 100);
```

This, in conjunction with using `e.which` with `e.keyCode` as Blender suggested should fix your issue.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure the name is correct? [.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework) has a habit of renaming things. You don't specify the language or environment.

Try to use the class selector. Give the button a class name of `class="Test"` and then select using `$(".Text").focus()`.

Answer (score -1):

Make sure the DOM is ready, element exists, before attempting to set focus.

Comment: His not trying to focus the button on the document load.