# Focus on readonly input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, forms

I have a form with three inputs the last of them has the `readonly` property, so the focus is missing because the way that the user fills the last input is by clicking some buttons, like a virtual keyboard. So everything works fine. But I'm trying to press `enter` and submit my form but since I lost the focus after the second input, my submit is not working. How can I resolve this?

**form.html**

```
<form name="myForm"
          role="form" 
          ng-submit="signin()" 
          novalidate>

        <input type="text" name="input1"/>
        <input type="text" name="input2"/>

        <div ng-controller="mycontroller">
            <span ng-click="fillInput3()">A</span>
            <span ng-click="fillInput3()">B</span>
            <span ng-click="fillInput3()">C</span>
        </div>
        <input type="text" name="input3" readonly=""/>

        <button type="submit">Ok</button>
    </form>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7802510/setting-focus-on-a-button-is-not-working

Comment: I have never used [tag:angularjs] but in plain html and javascript you can set a [tabindex](http://w3c.github.io/html-reference/global-attributes.html#common.attrs.tabindex) of controls.

Comment: Ricardo, updated my answer!!

Comment: @threeFourOneSixOneThree but in some cases I do not press the `tab` key in my last input, since this input is filled by the action of buttons.

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

give an id to your button,

```
<button type="submit" id="submitButton">Ok</button>
```

In your controller, insert `$window` as the dependency,

```
app.controller('yourController', function($scope, $window){

})
```

Then in `fillInput3()` function write this,

```
    var element = $window.document.getElementById("submitButton");
    if(element)
    element.focus();
```

This would focus the "submit" button as you exit the `fillInput3()` function.

Comment: Same result here :(, clean console using $window or using $jquery is not working.